# How to map Post/[id]/Comments/[Action] in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to create a RESTful API for my blog application but I can't tell how to map controllers like this.
How can it be done? Should Post be hardcoded in the URL pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could map a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "ShowComments", // Route name
        "Post/{id}/Comments/{action}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "CommentsController", action = "Show" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

There's nothing wrong with hardcoding URLs unless everything you add needs hardcoded URLs and they become unmaintainable.

What I understand is you want CommentsController called by only this route. You do not want it to be called by the default route. You can use `IgnoreRoute` for that.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute(“Comments/{action}/{id}”);
}
```

This will make sure CommentsController doesn't get called without the route we defined before. I hope that was what you were trying to do.

Comment: What does the use of brackets ([]) indicate vs braces ({})?

Comment: Sorry for that. Both should have been braces.

Comment: np, thought there was some cool functionality that I did not know about :-)

Comment: The question is: Can't a controller have "sub-controllers"?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. Last sentence in your question made me think it was about routes. Maybe you want to give more details about the problem.

Comment: @Ufuk Hacıoğulları: It is about routes. But that route represent a resource. I am just wondering if there is a way to specify that the Comments controller is a controller that is accessible only through a Post/ URL through code and not configuration. But generally you are correct.